# Tactile User Interface in android: How to develop android app UI as shown in the below image? This design is called tactile

Tags: android, user-interface

[image]

I want to develop UI as in the image attached. Which looks like bulged views.When clicked the views shall go inside, that is it looks like pressed button state of any hardware button.

How to achieve this? I researched, and all I could get is regarding material design. Does android provide any flexibility to develop such UI?
Please give your valuable inputs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to indicate state between normal and pushed, you would use a [selector (StateListDrawable)](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html).

Those buttons could simply be designed with the selector as the [background](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:background) of an `ImageButton`.

The selector would have two states, normal and pressed. Each of these states would have a drawable defined as a [NinePatchDrawable](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/help/draw9patch.html). That lets your icon expand as necessary.

The [src image](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:src) would be the smaller icon.